# How to insert a datagridview into a single cell of another datagridview in c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

//    i want to insert complete datagridview   contents into datagridview cell.

```
 DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
    dgv.Columns.Add("PName", "PName");
    dgv.Columns.Add("Qty", "Quantity");
    dgv.Columns.Add("Total", "Total");
    foreach (DataRow IRow in DTInv.Rows)
              {
               DataGridViewRow r = new DataGridViewRow();

           r.Cells[1].Value = Convert.ToString(IRow["PName"]);
               r.Cells[2].Value = Convert.ToString(IRow["Quantity"]);
               r.Cells[3].Value = Convert.ToString(IRow["TotalPrice"]);
               dgv.Rows.Add(r);
               }
    row.Cells[2].Value = dgv;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try it by modifying your last line of code as:

```
row.Cells[2].Controls.Add(dgv);
```